MagnifyingGlass jetpack compose
Any suggestions on how to create on Jetpack Composer Magnifying Glass the way it is in the video?
Magnifying Glass shows up and slightly zooms as the user long clicks. It can be moved all around the image.
ios implementation using 3-rd party library

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
